# Object destructuring - How to rewrite this function in a shorter way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am using babel and ES6, I would like to know if it is possible to write the following code in a shorter way, specially I do not like the manual remap pf property in the return statement.

```
  const locations = action.payload.list.map(location => {
    return {
      id: location.id,
      name: location.name,
      country: location.sys.country
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize object destructuring to get `"id"`, `"name"` and `"sys"` properties from current object at iteration. Since we want to get the `"country"` property from `"sys"` object, we perform an additional destructuring of `"sys"` property to get the `"country"` property, the syntax being `propertyNameOfObjectReference:{propertyNameOfNestedObjectToGet}`; note the colon `:` preceding next curly brace `{` where `propertyNameOfNestedObjectToGet` is surrounded by object literal curly braces `{`, `}`.

Note also, the value for `"name"` was string at stacksnippets where should be number; `name` can be globally defined as the string `window.name` in certain environments. To prevent possible issue as to type casting of value you can set `"name"` property a variable name other than `name` at destructuring, then setting property to `"name"` at returned object.

```js
const action = {payload:{list:[{name:123,id:456,sys:{country:789}}]}};

const locations = action.payload.list.map(({id, name:_name, sys:{country}}) =>
                    ({id, name:_name, country}));
   
console.log(locations);
```

Comment: Thanks, I really like this one, could you please add an additional explanation.

Comment: @Radex Which portion of `javascript` should additional explanation be attached to?

Comment: sys:{country} please ... I do not get it, it is like nested objects?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for example:

```
const locations = action.payload.list.map(({ id, name, sys }) => ({
  id,
  name,
  country: sys.country
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

An arrow function can return an object literal by wrapping it with parentheses:

```
const locations = action.payload.list.map(location => ({
  id: location.id,
  name: location.name,
  country: location.sys.country,
}))
```

Apart from that, there’s not much you can do unless it’s acceptable to include more properties:

```
const locations = action.payload.list.map(
  location => ({ ...location, ...location.sys }))
```